# WPF - Detect mouse down for a set period of time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouseevent

what's the best way to detect when a mouse button has been held down on a particular element for a specific period of time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` handlers to the object. In the `MouseDown` record `DateTime.Now`. If in the `MouseUp` handler:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(clickTime).TotalSeconds > your_seconds_value
```

then fire a new event `MouseClickedForXseconds`.

If you don't want to wait for a mouse up event then you need to start a timer on the `MouseDown` method which fires your `MouseClickedForXSeconds` event. This timer will be canceled by a mouse up event.

Comment: +1. It might also be worth considering using the StopWatch class rather than recording DateTime.Now, depending on how much accuracy is required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for the tip, I've made an attached property to avoid any codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// Represents a particular mouse button being pressed
/// </summary>
public enum MouseButtonType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default selection
    /// </summary>
    None,

    /// <summary>
    /// Left mouse button
    /// </summary>
    Left,

    /// <summary>
    /// Right mouse button
    /// </summary>
    Right,

    /// <summary>
    /// Either mouse button
    /// </summary>
    Both
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides functionality for detecting when a mouse button has been held
/// </summary>
public class MouseDownWait
{
    /// <summary>
    /// States which mouse button press should be detected
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MouseButton",
            typeof(MouseButtonType),
            typeof(MouseDownWait),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                (o, e) =>
                    {
                    var ctrl = o as UIElement;
                    if (ctrl != null)
                    {
                        new MouseDownWait(ctrl);
                    }
                }));

    /// <summary>
    /// The time (in milliseconds) to wait before detecting mouse press
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Time", typeof(int), typeof(MouseDownWait), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, OnTimePropertyChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to be called when the mouse press is detected
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DetectMethodProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DetectMethod",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MouseDownWait));

    /// <summary>
    /// Target object for the method calls (if not the datacontext)
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MethodTargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MethodTarget", typeof(object), typeof(MouseDownWait));      

    /// <summary>
    /// The timer used to detect mouse button holds
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    /// <summary>
    /// The element containing the attached property
    /// </summary>
    private readonly UIElement element;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MouseDownWait"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    public MouseDownWait(UIElement element)
    {
        this.element = element;

        if (this.element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.element.MouseLeftButtonDown += ElementMouseLeftButtonDown;
        this.element.MouseLeftButtonUp += ElementMouseLeftButtonUp;
        this.element.MouseRightButtonDown += ElementMouseRightButtonDown;
        this.element.MouseRightButtonUp += ElementMouseRightButtonUp;
        this.element.MouseDown += ElementMouseDown;
        this.element.MouseUp += ElementMouseUp;

        Timer.Tick += this.TimerTick;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mouse button type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mouse button type
    /// </returns>
    public static MouseButtonType GetMouseButton(UIElement element)
    {
        return (MouseButtonType)element.GetValue(MouseButtonProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the mouse button type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The type of mouse button</param>
    public static void SetMouseButton(UIElement element, MouseButtonType value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MouseButtonProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns>The time in milliseconds</returns>
    public static int GetTime(UIElement element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(TimeProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetTime(UIElement element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TimeProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the detect method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetDetectMethod(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DetectMethodProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the detect method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns>method name</returns>
    public static string GetDetectMethod(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(DetectMethodProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the method target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrl">The CTRL .</param>
    /// <returns>method target (i.e. viewmodel)</returns>
    public static object GetMethodTarget(UIElement ctrl)
    {
        var result = ctrl.GetValue(MethodTargetProperty);
        if (result == null)
        {
            var fe = ctrl as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                result = fe.DataContext;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the method target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrl">The CTRL .</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetMethodTarget(UIElement ctrl, object value)
    {
        ctrl.SetValue(MethodTargetProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the time property changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">The dependency object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void OnTimePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((int)e.NewValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a mouse down is detected
    /// </summary>
    private static void MouseDownDetected()
    {
        Timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a mouse up is detected
    /// </summary>
    private static void MouseUpDetected()
    {
        Timer.Stop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the mouse button has been detected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The mouse button type.</param>
    /// <param name="mouseDown">if set to <c>true</c> [mouse down].</param>
    private static void CheckMouseDetected(object sender, MouseButtonType type, bool mouseDown)
    {
        var uiElement = sender as UIElement;

        if (uiElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (GetMouseButton(uiElement) != type)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (mouseDown)
        {
            MouseDownDetected();
        }
        else
        {
            MouseUpDetected();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the mouse down event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Both, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the mouse up event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Both, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the left mouse down event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Left, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the left mouse up event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Left, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the right mouse down event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Right, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the right mouse up event fires
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void ElementMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckMouseDetected(sender, MouseButtonType.Right, false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called on each timer tick
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Stop();

        var method = GetDetectMethod(this.element);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
        {
            this.InvokeMethod(method);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">Name of the method.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters.</param>
    private void InvokeMethod(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var target = GetMethodTarget(this.element);
        var targetMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        if (targetMethod == null)
        {
            throw new MissingMethodException(methodName);
        }

        targetMethod.Invoke(target, parameters);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Transparent" 
        local:MouseDownWait.MouseButton="Both"
        local:MouseDownWait.Time="1000"
        local:MouseDownWait.DetectMethod="MouseDetected">

        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28"  />

</Border>
```

This will call a method on your DataContext (ViewModel) when the specified time has ellapsed.  You can detect Left, Right, or Both mouse buttons.

Comment: +1. Nice solution. Just handle handle MouseLeave as well with Timer.Stop();

Comment: @devdigital - I have a similar problem I am trying to solve with a sensitive touch screen.  I need to filter out finger touches which are caused by parts of the hand passing close to the screen and would like to try using custom buttons which detect slightly longer presses.  It looks like what you are doing above might work but could you explain how this code gets integrated into an application.

Comment: If I apply the attached property on multiple controls the different Detect methods are fired regardless of the clicked control, is it possible to make this work as a regular instance instead of static?

Comment: MatiasK, I fixed that issue by adding a private non-static bool called pressed.  In CheckMouseDetected, put pressed = true under if (mouseDown) and put pressed = false under else.  Then in TimerTick, change the line to if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method) && pressed).  At the end of TimerTick, add pressed = false.