# WPF - Open ContextMenu on left mouse hold down

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu, onmousedown

In Google Chrome I really like the functionality of the left mouse hold down on the Back button to get the full browse history.

In my WPF app: for a button with a context menu, how can I open the menu on hold down of the left mouse (and of course still with the regular right click)?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428494/wpf-detect-mouse-down-for-a-set-period-of-time 
Its accepted answer is a lot better than that of this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to handle the `MouseDown` event by starting a timer there. If the `MouseUp` event is fired, the timer needs to be stopped. You can use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945.aspx) for that. Then you can set up a time after that the `Timer_Tick` event should be fired, where you can perform the action you would like to perform. In order to avoid problems with the bubbling `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events, I would suggest to add the two handlers in the window constructor instead of adding them in XAML (at least the events did not fire in my example code, so i changed that) by using

```
button1.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseDown), true);
button1.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseUp), true);
```

Additionally, you need to set up the timer there:

Add a field to the window class:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

and set up the timer with the time you want to wait until the `Timer_Tick` event is fired (also in the window constructor):

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
// time until Tick event is fired
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

Then you only need to handle the events and you are done:

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    timer.Start();
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    timer.Stop();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    timer.Stop();
    // perform certain action
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only way is to manually process MouseDown/Move/Up events over the button, wait for a certain amount of time to pass after MouseDown occured and if in this amount of time you don't have a MouseMove or MouseUp event, then manually show the ContextMenu. If you show the context menu, you'll have to take care for the button not to generate a Click event after that and to do it's default click action.